# NullPointerException when setting enabled to false in htmlcompressor maven plugin

Tags: plugins, maven, nullpointerexception

I get a null pointer exception when setting `enabled` to `false` (as described in the [doc](https://github.com/TUNYK/htmlcompressor-maven-plugin/wiki/Configuration)):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlcompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>html</goal>
                </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <goalPrefix>htmlcompressor</goalPrefix>
                <srcFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/html</srcFolder>
                <targetFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/result/html</targetFolder>
                <removeIntertagSpaces>true</removeIntertagSpaces>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Anyone knows why? Anyone has a solution?

**P.S.**: Here is maven -X:

```
[htmlcompressor:html]
com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor-maven-plugin:jar:1.2:
   com.googlecode.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor:jar:1.4:compile
   com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:jar:r1043:compile
      args4j:args4j:jar:2.0.12:compile
      com.google.guava:guava:jar:r08:compile
      com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.3.0:compile
      org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.1:compile
         org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.1:compile
      com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
      junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:compile
   com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:jar:2.4.6:compile
      rhino:js:jar:1.6R7:compile
   javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:compile
   org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
      commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
      commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
      commons-chain:commons-chain:jar:1.1:compile
      commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
      commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
         javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile
      commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.3.1:compile
      dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.1:compile
      oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
      sslext:sslext:jar:1.2-0:compile
      org.apache.struts:struts-core:jar:1.3.8:compile
         antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.2:compile
      org.apache.struts:struts-taglib:jar:1.3.8:compile
      org.apache.struts:struts-tiles:jar:1.3.8:compile
      org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.2:compile
         commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
   org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
   org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0.3:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.3:compile
         org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0.3:compile
      org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:2.1.1:compile
         org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
         org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.4:compile
         org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.1.1:compile
            org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:2.9.4:compile
   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.10:compile
   org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.10:compile
      log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
Created new class realm plugin>com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor-maven-plugin:1.2
Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor-maven-plugin:1.2
  Imported:  < maven.api
Populating class realm plugin>com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor-maven-plugin:1.2
  Included: com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor-maven-plugin:jar:1.2
  Included: com.googlecode.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor:jar:1.4
  Included: com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:jar:r1043
  Included: args4j:args4j:jar:2.0.12
  Included: com.google.guava:guava:jar:r08
  Included: com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.3.0
  Included: org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.1
  Included: org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.1
  Included: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9
  Included: junit:junit:jar:4.8.2
  Included: com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:jar:2.4.6
  Included: rhino:js:jar:1.6R7
  Included: javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1
  Included: org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0
  Included: commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0
  Included: commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8
  Included: commons-chain:commons-chain:jar:1.1
  Included: commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2
  Included: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1
  Included: javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3
  Included: commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.3.1
  Included: dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.1
  Included: oro:oro:jar:2.0.8
  Included: sslext:sslext:jar:1.2-0
  Included: org.apache.struts:struts-core:jar:1.3.8
  Included: antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.2
  Included: org.apache.struts:struts-taglib:jar:1.3.8
  Included: org.apache.struts:struts-tiles:jar:1.3.8
  Included: org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.2
  Included: commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4
  Included: org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
  Included: org.json:json:jar:20090211
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.6
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
  Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.1.1
  Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:2.9.4
  Included: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.10
  Included: org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.10
  Included: log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0.3
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.3
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0.3
  Excluded: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:2.1.1
  Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.4
Configuring mojo com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor-maven-plugin:1.2:html from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor-maven-plugin:1.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7]
Configuring mojo 'com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor-maven-plugin:1.2:html' with basic configurator -->
  (s) closureCustomExternsOnly = false
  (s) closureExterns = []
  (s) closureOptLevel = simple
  (s) compressCss = false
  (s) compressJavaScript = false
  (s) enabled = false
  (s) encoding = utf-8
  (s) fileExt = []
  (s) generateStatistics = true
  (s) htmlCompressionStatistics = C:\Users\...\Documents\Java\NewBigBag\Convert-Kit\trunk\target/htmlcompressor/html-compression-statistics.txt
  (s) javascriptHtmlSprite = true
  (s) javascriptHtmlSpriteIntegrationFile = C:\Users\...\Documents\Java\NewBigBag\Convert-Kit\trunk/src/main/resources/html/integration.js
  (s) javascriptHtmlSpriteTargetFile = C:\Users\JVerstry\Documents\Java\NewBigBag\Convert-Kit\trunk\target/htmlcompressor/html/integration.js
  (s) jsCompressor = yui
  (s) predefinedPreservePatterns = []
  (s) preservePatternFiles = []
  (s) preservePatterns = []
  (s) removeComments = true
  (s) removeFormAttributes = false
  (s) removeHttpProtocol = false
  (s) removeHttpsProtocol = false
  (s) removeInputAttributes = false
  (s) removeIntertagSpaces = true
  (s) removeJavaScriptProtocol = false
  (s) removeLinkAttributes = false
  (s) removeMultiSpaces = true
  (s) removeQuotes = false
  (s) removeScriptAttributes = false
  (s) removeStyleAttributes = false
  (s) simpleBooleanAttributes = false
  (s) simpleDoctype = false
  (s) srcFolder = C:\Users\...\Documents\Java\NewBigBag\Convert-Kit\trunk/src/main/webapp/html
  (s) targetFolder = C:\Users\...\Documents\Java\NewBigBag\Convert-Kit\trunk/src/main/webapp/result/html
  (s) yuiCssLineBreak = -1
  (s) yuiJsDisableOptimizations = false
  (s) yuiJsLineBreak = -1
  (s) yuiJsNoMunge = false
  (s) yuiJsPreserveAllSemiColons = false
-- end configuration --
Compressing C:\Users\...\Documents\Java\NewBigBag\Convert-Kit\trunk/src/main/webapp/html
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2:01.151s
Finished at: Sun Jan 29 11:55:23 CET 2012
Final Memory: 16M/47M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor-maven-plugin:1.2:html (default) on project convertkit: Execution default of goal com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor-maven-plugin:1.2:html failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor-maven-plugin:1.2:html (default) on project convertkit: Execution default of goal com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor-maven-plugin:1.2:html failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor-maven-plugin:1.2:html failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor.HtmlCompressorMojo.execute(HtmlCompressorMojo.java:417)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: It's probably a bug in the plugin, please fill an issue : https://github.com/TUNYK/htmlcompressor-maven-plugin/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bug of htmlcompressor-maven-plugin.
The fix has been committed and release 1.3 has been scheduled on Feb 5th.
With version 1.3 you'll see message "HTML compression was turned off." or "XML compression was turned off." in case of property "enabled" is set to false.